# Invalid Date : Record is Read Only

Tags: trigger

I am trying to write  Apex trigger for Account that matches Shipping Address Postal Code with Billing Address Postal Code based on a custom field.

```
public class TriggerOnAccountHandler {
    public static void onInsert(List<Account> newListAccount){
        for(Account acc : newListAccount){
            if(acc.BillingPostalCode !=Null && acc.Same_as_billing_Address_Postal_Code__c == true){
                acc.ShippingPostalCode  = acc.BillingPostalCode;
            }
        }
    }
}

trigger TriggerOnAccount on Account (after insert, after update) {
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
        TriggerOnAccountHandler.onInsert(Trigger.New);
    }
}
```

> Error while saving the Account Record :
>
> Error: Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. Apex trigger TriggerOnAccount caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: TriggerOnAccount: execution of AfterInsert
>   caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only:
>   Class.TriggerOnAccountHandler.onInsert: line 5, column 1

Comment: this error comes when you try to update after event trigger records... use before event

Answer (score 0):

After insert operation records of Sobject are read-only. You have to make a query on Account with the help of i`d=: Trigger.NewMap.keySet()` and process the records in your handler. 
Hope it helps you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change that **"after insert" to "before insert"** in the trigger and **isAfter to isBefore**.  (both places)

```
trigger TriggerOnAccount on Account (before insert, after update) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
        TriggerOnAccountHandler.onInsert(Trigger.New);
    }
}
```